# HTML-like tables in pyqt

Tags: python, html, pyqt, html-table, qt-quick

I'm currently starting a little program in `python` and `pyqt`. I have little to no experience on GUI programming but I need a table to present some items (like one in this website [HERE](http://www.battigayo.com/schedule) ). I was wondering if there was any way to do this in `pyqt` (`qtquick` would be better) .

I know there is qtableview in `pyqt` but I need to make it look like an html table. Can Qtableview be made to look like a `CSS` style `HTML` table?

Comment: How do you mean you want it to look like a HTML table? With the right CSS an HTML table can look like anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`QTableView`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtableview.html)s inherit from [`QWidget`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html)s you can just use the [`setStyleSheet`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#setStyleSheet) method to override any default styles for the table.

Depending on how you want to style the table specifically, you'll definitely want to review the  [Qt Style Syntax](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html).

As per the comment, if you just want to disable sorting call [`yourTable.setSortingEnabled(False)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html#setSortingEnabled), and call 
[`yourTable.verticalHeader().setMovable(False)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qheaderview.html#setMovable) (or `horizontalHeader`) to disable moving the headers, when creating the table.

Comment: If I could  remove the sorting and moving ability from it, that might just do the trick. Is it possible?

Comment: I think that'll do it. Thanks, I missed to notice them in the docs. Thanks again

Comment: Thats perfectly fine, the PyQt docs can be sparse at times, and I find it is a bit counter intuitive that disabling moving of rows/columns is on the headers, and not the table itself.